# Microsoft AdControl stealing focus - Windows 8 MonoGame

Tags: xaml, windows-8, focus, ads, monogame

I am currently writing a simple snake clone game for Windows 8 using MonoGame. I am using the XAML - MonoGame template and trying to include advertising support. I have found an issue, pretty sure it's with the AdControl itself, not MonoGame, however it is stealing keyboard focus every time an ad is loaded.

I have tried to reinitialize the MonoGame 'MetroGameWindow' instance to try and get focus back with no luck. Eg,

```
void GamePage_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MetroGameWindow.Instance.Initialize(Window.Current.CoreWindow,this)
    // 'this' is 'GamePage' which inherits from 'SwapChainBackgroundPanel'
}
```

Does any one know any workarounds for this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ia a known problem with AdControl. As of now best solution is to set IsEnabled property of AdControl to `false`. Doing so will prevent AdControl from taking focus on ad reloads while remaining clickable. See following discussion on bing ads forum: http://community.bingads.microsoft.com/ads/en/publisher/f/63/t/73548.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I found setting the Visibility to collapsed and back again also works, but one line is better than 2 :)