# Detecting when a user drags over an adcontrol in a HTML5/Javascript app?

Tags: javascript, windows, html, windows-8, ads

Hi I developed a game using Construct2 and included an AdControl inside main html page that came with the exported project. Now I noticed when you drag from the game canvas onto the ad and release, it never actually releases the touch. My game is dependent on a particular touch so I actually need that touch to reset if the user stops touching the screen. Am I missing something here, or is there maybe a workaround for this issue? I tried out the same thing in C#, using a WebBrowser control and I didn't experience the same issue.

I have tried a few things like HTML fragments and separating the div from the canvas with margins but it always acts the same way. I also tried to include the ad using a Windows Runtime Component but it doesn't look like it allows you to pass UI elements like the AdControl. Does anyone have some suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Talking about touches you probably need to read this : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/
What kind of events you are you using ? are you using mouseClick, mouseOver ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example which releases the touch when the hand is moved over the ad : http://jsfiddle.net/ChaitanyaMunipalle/jn3kZ/

You can see all the touch events below the canvas in this jsfiddle.

Check HammerJs for drag, release and other touch gestures. You can use touch events like normal jquery events like

```
$('#canvasId').on('dragstart drag dragend release ....',callback);
```

Answer (score 2):

Some possibly related problem and solutions.

[AdControl takes control over Focus](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/winappswithcsharp/thread/260fde69-3738-49a3-b4f1-6514389d5efd) - two possible solutions.

1. > try to set IsEnabled property to false.
2. > Found a slightly more effective workaround (which lets you leave the
   >   AdControl fully enabled).
   >
   > 1. Create a Boolean field to called "`_advertRefreshed`".
   > 2. During `ApplyTemplates` hook the `AdControl.Refreshed` event, setting the `_advertRefreshed` true.
   > 3. Add a `OnLostFocus` event which implements the logic "if current focus is WebView and `_advertRefreshed` is true set focus back to
   >      original, then following this test always `set _advertRefreshed` false
   >      again".

[KeyPress swallowed by AdControl?](http://community.bingads.microsoft.com/ads/en/publisher/f/63/t/73548.aspx) - a discussion on the issue and confirmation on solution #1 above.

[Microsoft AdControl stealing focus - Windows 8 MonoGame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12965318/microsoft-adcontrol-stealing-focus-windows-8-monogame)

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately this solution only applies to XAML applications and not the HTML5/JavaScript template that I'm currently using for my game. I did check the AdControl for HTML however, but there was no enabled property.

Comment: Have you looked into the `IsEngagedChanged` event? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-adcontrol-silverlight-isengagedchanged-event(v=msads.20).aspx

Comment: I have. Not sure how I can use it though. Any ideas? I guess we would probably try to cancel the event.

Answer (score 2):

I'd need to see your code to give you the best answer possible, but this problem is fairly common.

If you have a setup like this (using jQuery for concept demonstration):

```
var mDown = false;

$("#myDiv").mouseDown(function(){
    mDown = true;
}).mouseMove(function(e){
    if (mDown)
       // do stuff
}).mouseUp(function(){
    mDown = false;
});
```

What happens is, if you mousedown inside of the div, but mouseup outside of it, the flag is never cleared because that div never receives the mouseup event.

What you need to do instead is attach the mouseup event to the window or document:

```
$(window).mouseUp(function(){
    mDown = false;
});
```

It will then clear its "state" regardless of where you release the mouse button.